# How to open a new View Controller (inside UINavigation stack) from UICollectionView Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I'm a new in iOS development and I faced a difficult task for me :)

I have a View Controller(ViewController()) with UICollectionView. When I click on a UICollectionView Cell, a new View Controller(SpartakViewController()) should be pushed (this new VC should be inside the UINavigation stack).

I have 4 files:

1. **ViewController**: UIViewController - for setup VC
2. **GalleryCollectionView**: UICollectionView - for setup Collection View
3. **GalleryCollectionViewCel**l: UICollectionViewCell - for setup Collection View Cell
4. **SpartakViewController**: UIViewController - for setup Spartak VC

So, I want to create a UINavigationController (only programmatically, without Storyboard),  put 2 ViewControllers on UINavigation stack.
How can I create UINavigation Controller correctly?
This is a code from my Scene Delegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    navigationController.viewControllers = [ViewController(),SpartakViewController()]
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Then I want to push SpartakViewController() when I click on UICollectionView Cell. Should I do it via **didSelectItemAt** property for UICollectionView?
I suppose I can do it via the following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let navController = self.navigationController else { return } 
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let spartakVC = SpartakViewController()
        navController.pushViewController(spartakVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

but it didn't work. Where am I wrong? What is the best file to do this?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint inside the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` method, does it stop there once you tap? And if it does, does it reach the `pushViewController(_:animated)` method?

Comment: What is the point of setting navigationController.viewControllers ? This must only be done to change the navigation stack. And you only push SpartakViewConttollet for first item ?

Comment: Updates: I have added `galleryCollectionView.delegate = self` line in my ViewController() and also I have added an extension: 

`extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            let spartakVC = SpartakViewController()
            navController.pushViewController(spartakVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}`
And now when I click to any cell, my Spartak VC opens.